# innerHTML - td element

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to add rows dynamically using dojo
The code is working fine in IE 9 Document mode, but throwing error in IE8.
Can anyone rectify this?

This is the sample code.

```
var tr1 = dojo.create("tr",{name:'eSigntr',id:'eSigntr_'+rowNo_form});
tr1.setAttribute('class','altrow');
dojo.place(tr1,tBody);

var td1 = dojo.create("td",{width:'5%', style:{'text-align':'left', 'verticalAlign':'middle'}, align:'center'}, tr1);
td1.innerHTML = "<strong>Page #:</strong> ";
```

**Exception is in the line td1.innerHTML**

```
SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error test.js, line 883 character 2
```

Screenshots are attached for both verrsion

### IE 9

As you can see, a new row has been added after checking the radio button - **Page#**

[image: As you can see, a new row has been added after checking the radio button - **Page#**]

### IE 8

The row is not coming in IE8

[image: The row is not coming in IE8]

getting the error

```
SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error test.js, line 883 character 2
```

Comment: which line of you samplecode is `line 883`?

Comment: Getting error in this line 
td1.innerHTML = "<strong>Page #:</strong> ";

Answer (score 0):

`<strong>` is an HTML 5 element. I am 99% certain that IE8 does not support the `<strong>` element.
See here [strong and b element for IE8](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/strong-and-b-elements.htm)
Try changing the  element to bold i.e `<b>`.
Hope it helps.